# Why is Rc::downgrade(this: &Self) instead of Rc::downgrade(&self)

Tags: rust

Is there any particular reason why the type signature of `Rc::downgrade` doesn't use `&self` and instead `this: &Self` as parameter?

To avoid Naming pollution when `deref`ing? But why does `Weak` then use `Weak::upgrade(&self)` instead of `Weak::upgrade(this: &Self)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> To avoid Naming pollution when `deref`ing?

Exactly. Lots of built-in containers like `Rc` and `Box` try very hard to minimize the number of inherent functions defined on them, favoring associated functions instead to allow the structure to be as transparent as possible.

[`Weak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Weak.html), on the other hand, does not implement `Deref`. You *must* consciously try to get the value from it, using `upgrade`, and that function can fail (a `Deref` impl should never fail) if the value pointed to has already been dropped.